# destroy directive/child scope on scope destroy

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a directive that compiles another directive and attaches it to the body with the same scope passed. This will not be the same location as the "parent" directive.

When the parent directive gets destroyed is there some way to have the child directive and scope destroy as well? I ask because after inspecting the DOM the child directive is still there.

Currently I hook into the parents $destroy event but was curious if it could be handled automatically.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FPx4G/1/

The child stays there as you toggle the parent, but i'd like to to be destroyed. What would be the best method to do that?

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <button data-ng-click="toggleParent()">Toggle Parent</button>
        <div data-ng-switch data-on="displayDirective">
            <div data-ng-switch-when="true">
                <div class="parentDirective">Parent Directive</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive("parentDirective", function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function(scope, element){
                var secondDirective = angular.element(document.createElement("div"));
                secondDirective.addClass("childDirective");

                document.body.appendChild(secondDirective[0]);

                $compile(secondDirective)(scope);
            }
        }
    })
    .directive("childDirective", function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            template: '<div>Child Directive</div>',
            link: function(scope, element){
                scope.$on("destroy", function(){
                   alert(1); 
                });
            }
        }
    });


function ParentCtrl($scope){
   $scope.displayDirective = true;
    $scope.toggleParent = function(){
        $scope.displayDirective = !$scope.displayDirective;
    }
}
```

Normally, I'd just have the sub element within the original directive's template so that it's positioned correctly. The issue really comes down to dealing with z-index. The parent element is in a container that can be scrolled, so the child (in one case a *custom* dropdown) would be hidden/cut off if it was larger then the container. To combat this I instead create the actual child in the document body and position it relative to the parent. It would also listen in on scroll events to reposition itself. I have that all working and is just fine. It's what happens when I need to delete the parent... the child is still there.

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality in Angular. I believe you can a service to handle this for you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This seems like a very convoluted way to do this.

Comment: See my latest edit near the bottom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
directive("childDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',              
        template: '<div >Child Directive</div>',                
        link: function(scope, element){                  
            scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
                element.remove();
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C8hs6/

Comment: I was hoping not to have to listen to the scope destroy event. If this is the only way to do it though so be it.

Comment: Had it been child element actually under DOM relationship then you angular would have cleaned it up...but you scenario is quite different here so this is the trick to handle it.

Comment: Just FYI, the element is already an Angular wrapped element, so this also works: `element.remove()`.