# Memory leak when using angular's $compile with a new scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, memory-leaks

I want to dynamically create angular components using javascript, and then have angular compile them using `$compile` with a newly created scope. Then when I have no longer use for that component, I want to destroy the component and the new scope.

Everything works as expected, except from the fact that even though I am destroying the new scope, all the memory that it uses is never released.

Here is part of a simplified version of that code:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$compile", function($scope, $compile) {
    var childScope;

    //call this every time the button is clicked
    this.createDirective = function() {
        //dynamically create a new instance of the custom directive
        var customDirective = document.createElement("custom-directive");

        //if another child scope exists, destroy it
        if (childScope) {
            childScope.$destroy();
            childScope = undefined;
        }

        //create a new child scope
        childScope = $scope.$new();

        //compile the custom directive
        $compile(customDirective)(childScope);
    };

}]);
```

Full working example of this code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yqw1dk0w/4/)

All this code does, is create a new component every time the button is clicked, but first destroy any component that already exists.
Notice that I am not actually adding the compiled component in the page, because I noticed that the leak was still there regardless of whether I used it or not.

Using Chrome's development tools (Profiles -> Record Allocation Timeline -> Start) I see the following memory usage after clicking the button 
a few times:

[Memory consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzDQ8.png)

It is clear that any memory occupied by the customDirective is never actually released, even though the scope's `$destroy` function is being called.

I have successfully used `$compile` in the past without creating a new scope, but it seems that I am missing something in this scenario. Should I be doing something else as well to make sure that there are no references to the new scope?

## Edit

Based on the answer below by JoelCDoyle, here is the fix (I add an on destroy function to the scopes I create):

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$compile", function($scope, $compile) {
    var childScope;

    //call this every time the button is clicked
    this.createDirective = function() {
        //dynamically create a new instance of the custom directive
        var customDirective = document.createElement("custom-directive");

        //if another child scope exists, destroy it
        if (childScope) {
            childScope.$destroy();
            childScope = undefined;
        }

        //create a new child scope
        childScope = $scope.$new();

        //compile the custom directive
        var compiledElement = $compile(customDirective)(childScope);

        //FIX: remove the angular element
        childScope.$on("$destroy", function() {
            compiledElement.remove();
        });
    };
}]);
```

[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqw1dk0w/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a solution to this: https://jsfiddle.net/yqw1dk0w/8/

```
app.directive('customDirective', function(){
  return {
    template: '<div ng-controller="customDirectiveCtrl"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        element.remove();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I'm still a little fuzzy on why this works, but this section, **How Directives are Compiled**, in angular compile docs provides a clue: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

> $compile links the template with the scope by calling the combined
>   linking function from the previous step. This in turn will call the
>   linking function of the individual directives, **registering listeners
>   on the elements** and setting up $watchs with the scope as each
>   directive is configured to do.\
>
> The result of this is a live binding between the scope **and the DOM**. So at this > point, a change in a model on the compiled scope will be reflected in the DOM.

Destroying the scope, I'm guessing, does not remove these element listeners. That's what the above code is doing: [destroy directive/child scope on scope destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522426/destroy-directive-child-scope-on-scope-destroy)

Comment: This does indeed look very promising as it fixes the fiddle example. I will apply it to my application and see if it works there as well

Comment: Yes! this also works for my more complicated application..!
Though.. I still don't exactly understand *why* this works. I am not adding it in the DOM, so why does it need to be removed? 
Also, even when I was adding the compiled element to the DOM and then removing it, the memory was still leaking.

Is $compile adding this somewhere else as well? like maybe a cache..?

Answer (score 1):

It will start deallocating if you put array to scope and de-allocate it

```
$scope.array.length = 0;
```

to the destcructor. But... nice to know. I'll have to watch closely memory consumption. Seems that scope is retained. Cause I am only de-allocating inner variables.

Comment: `this.array` is undefined inside of the destroy listener (set the array using a `var` instead of `this`), but the method is sound. The garbage collection reclaims the memory. Nice!

Comment: ah... true, I reassigned it to scope to be able to deallocate. editing...

Comment: This is only taking care of the symptoms, it's not actually fixing the problem.
That array is only allocated to simulate memory used by a more complex component that cannot manually remove all the variables it is using

Comment: Both answers that you mentioned above get rid of the memory used by the array, but the scope is still there, in the memory. It is still not being released